# mutual information between the features and the class given the naive bayes assumption

Tags: machine-learning, naivebayes

I am reading a paper by Irina Rish(http://www.research.ibm.com/people/r/rish/papers/RC22230.pdf), and I would like to know what the notation I(C;(X1,X2)) i.e the mutual information between the features and the class, and also Inb(C;(X1,X2)) i.e the same quantity computed given the naive bayes assumption. More importantly, How will I go about calculating this on a training set such as the one shown below?﻿

[image]

Comment: Probably needs to be migrated to stats.

Comment: What do you mean by stats ?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Alright, thanks.....Although, I have been doing some digging around and from what I can understand (X1, X2) denotes the 'joint random variable. Therefore I(C;(X1, X2)) simply denotes the mutual information between the class labels and the joint random variables of the training set, now all I have to do is find out how to calculate the joint rand variable ..... correct me if I'm wrong